# How to scan through parts of an array in C Looking to match user input

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am having trouble figuring out how to read through an array in C. I am trying to match up user input with parts of the array. The array is filled from a text file that looks like this:

```
1754
1350
```

and so on. There are a total of 8 four digit numbers in the array as of right now. I want the ability to add more of these numbers into the text file and still be able to use the same code to scan through the array with the user input. Here is the code that I am working on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*this is to test strings*/
int main ()
{

    FILE* spEmployees;
    printf("Enter the code:");
    char A[100];
    scanf("%c", A);
    char empNum[100];//stores empolyee numbers
    spEmployees = fopen("Employees.txt", "r");
    if (spEmployees == NULL)
    {
        printf("fail\n");
    }
    else
    {
        int num_lines = 0;
        while ( !feof (spEmployees) && fgets(empNum, 99, spEmployees ))
        {
            printf("%s", empNum);
            num_lines ++;
        }
    }
    fclose(spEmployees);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

So right now I do not have anything in place for scanning or comparing the array. This works for getting the information from the text file for the array and reading the user input. I have tried nearly all the standard C string functions. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: `scanf("%c",...)` looks for a single-character input from the user, correct?

Comment: No, the input from the user should be 4 characters, in this case it will actually be ints but I store them in a char to be able to compare them. Does scanf have a problem with more than one character?

Comment: Then you should use `scanf("%s", A);`.

Comment: For searching the whole array on whether it matches a user's input, consider (A) putting all the file strings into a single long character array and using `strstr` to search it, or (B) converting each file item to a number before storing it in an array and also converting the user'a input to a number to attempt a match or (C) have an array of strings from the file and use `strstr` on each against the user's input to look for a match...

Comment: @master Ok, that has been switched over. That does work better now

Comment: @abiessu, upon some quick tests and minor changes to the file IT WORKS,  It correctly identified the user number with one of the numbers in the file/array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in my comment, the solution I would write would be some option among serializing the data into a single character array or converting everything to numbers for easy comparison or using an array of character arrays and string-comparing one-by-one.

Among these options, I think serializing the data would be easiest, although it would require (at least) one of the following conditions to be a correct solution:

1. regular data, all of which has exactly the same length/type
2. a spacing character, to mark the difference between one data item and another
3. a structure of some sort (more complicated than a single spacing character, but having the same effect)

Making an assumption that (1) is the case and the data arrives as 4-character strings as well as the user's input is limited to 4 characters, I might write

```
#define MAX_ITEMS 100
#define ITEM_SIZE 4
...
char fullSet[MAX_ITEMS*ITEM_SIZE+1];
int num_lines = 0;
while (!feof (spEmployees) && fgets(empNum, 99, spEmployees) && num_lines < MAX_ITEMS) {
    printf("%s", empNum);
    snprintf(&(fullSet[num_lines*ITEM_SIZE]), ITEM_SIZE+1, "%s", empNum);
    num_lines++;
}
char *idx = strstr(fullSet, A);
int isMatch = 0;
if (idx != NULL) {
    if ((int)(fullSet-idx) % ITEM_SIZE == 0)
        isMatch = 1;
}
// do something with having found a match...
```

Having once made the assumption in (1), and choosing to overwrite the separating `NULL` character in the string to make the math easier, the only thing I need to do to make sure that I don't get part of one string with part of another as a match is to determine whether the result of `strstr` starts at the "beginning" of one of the items in my serialization.  Of course, I did not check whether `A` contains a string longer or shorter than `ITEM_SIZE`, but that should be easy enough to figure out.

One hidden feature of this particular serialization is that `strstr` will search the entire `fullSet` variable for an instance of `A` instead of stopping after the first entry due to a `NULL` termination between entries.  Note that the last entry within `fullSet` will still have a terminating `NULL` from the last `snprintf(...)` call.

Comment: Thank you. @abiessu I used your the suggestion of strstr to compare the two stings. This works and allows for further entry into the file to expand it. I also used `atoi` to check them so `atoi(A)` and `atoi(empNum)` Then I could use them as I would standard an `int` This works but the program does not exit smoothly, I have it writing a time stamp with the number that the user entered to a file. It does print to file but then crashes instead of exiting smoothly, I might have to ask another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make these two things, right?:

- *"the ability to add more of these numbers into the text"*
- *"to use the same code to scan through the array with the user input."*

The following code includes these two abilities (*pay attention at the comments*):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*this is to test strings*/
int main ()
{

    FILE* spEmployees;
    char A[100];
    char *A_ptr = &A[0];
    char empNum[100];//stores empolyee numbers

    printf("Enter the code:");
    scanf("%s", A_ptr);

    spEmployees = fopen("Employees.txt", "r+"); // read/update

    if (spEmployees == NULL)
    {
        printf("fail\n");
    }
    else
    {
        int num_lines = 0;
        while ( !feof (spEmployees) && fgets(empNum, 99, spEmployees ))
        {
            printf("%s", empNum);
            num_lines ++;
        }

        // "the ability to add more of these numbers into the text file"
        fprintf(spEmployees, A);    

        // adding a new-line char to the file so the next number
        // will be written in the next line
        fprintf(spEmployees, "\n");
    }

    fclose(spEmployees);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Note** that the file must be such:

```
1754
1350

^
After writing manually `1350` to the file you need to go to the next line
so the program will write the new (entered) value to the file at the beginning
of the new line instead of continuing the 2nd:

1754
13502013   // like this
```

Comment: You did nothing with the entered code?  It looks almost like a copy of the code in the question...  I don't think printing the user's code to the file was of any interest to the OP.

Comment: @abiessu, later *see the **PS*** I'll explain. At the moment I can say that there was no **writing to the file** and the file was opened in a **read only** mode. (I really have no time now, see you later :))

Comment: I think one of the site guidelines is "ask for clarification in comments, not within an answer."  Setting that aside, it is easy to see that the three changed/added lines of code implement the quoted fixes.  What is not as clear to me is why you quoted the entire original code and made changes within it rather than only quoting the changes/additions plus a couple lines of context...

Comment: @abiessu, I think that's not very meaningful. Anyway, I had too little time to format the text so there will be only changed/added lines. And full code looks better rather than it's pieces. Thanx for paying attention: in future I'll post only changed\added lines of code.

Comment: @abiessu, update: if it turns out that I understood the question incorrectly, I'll remove (delete) this answer.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that, since you did offer an answer to a piece that may in fact be interesting relative to the question being asked.  My comments were intended to encourage what I consider to be improvements in your answer...